# How to test dynamic ip restriction in Azure App?

Tags: .net, ddos, dynamic-ip, azure-ddos

Hi I have developed SPA web application in Angular. I am using VS2017 and I am using MVC template. I have deployed my app in azure. My project has some server side code as well. I have added below policy to restrict concurrent requests to my web application. Below code I added in web.config. I am running my project in localhost:1148

```
 <security>
      <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Forbidden">
        <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="4" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="2000"/>
        <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="4"/>
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
 </security>
```

I want to test the above rule applied in localhost. I want to know Is it possible to test in above rule in localhost? When there are more then 4 concurrent requests O want to display forbidden. Can someone help me to test this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to publish your application to local IIS?   Make sure the IP security is included in your IIS. And test it with fiddler or CRTRL+ F5 to refresh the page.

Comment: I have deployed in azure not in iis. How can i tes in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also could test it with Filddler or other tool.For more details,please refer to the screenshot. You could test it by click the [Excute] quickly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried as you said. But my website never goes down. I tried quickly executing around 150 times. As per my above code my website supposed to go down right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should block your client Ip for a while.  Based on my test, if I set it in the Webconfig, then it  works correctly. In your case, I recommand that you could have a try to use Xdt transform and test it again and don't forget to reboot the WebApp after Xdt transform.

Comment: Thanks. Can i test it in localhost?

Comment: If you want to test it with local IIS, you need to make sure the IP security is included in your IIS, more details please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions).

Comment: I am running on iis express which is provided by default with VS2017. Can i do it in iis express too?

Comment: I came to office and tested and as per your first answer after five six successful attempts i started to get 403 error in fiddler. I hope I am on correct way. But how long my ip will be blocked? When i open website i got You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you tell me how long my ip address will be blocked?

Comment: Based on my understanding,according to your requestIntervalInMilliseconds and maxRequests setting. Usually, dynamicIpSecurity is used for protecting your app against DDOS